# Show preview text then show all (expand) on click of a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, textarea, preview, expand

I have a column in a table with data that uses a textarea that allows for in place editin using the best_in_place gem. It takes up a bit of space vertically. I want to show a preview of the text in the textarea and on the click of a button, the text will expand down and show the full textarea.

Is this possible?

```
    <td><%= best_in_place @obj, :comment , :type => :textarea %></td>
```

Comment: Why not limit textarea width and make it scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

Textarea's can only have text in them so there's no scope for hidden divs etc within the textarea itself.  The best approach i can think of is to hide the real textarea with the full data in it, and show a "dummy" textarea (eg with name "dummy") which has a truncated version of the data.

Then, when the user clicks the button (or perhaps anywhere in the textarea) you hide the dummy textarea and show the real  one.

You will need to stop the user from editing the dummy textarea, since this will get discarded: this is a good reason to swap out for the real one as soon as they click in it (or tab to it:  you should bind to the focus event actually since this will catch tabs too).

Something like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="preview">
    <div>
      <%= text_area_tag "dummy", <%= truncate(@foo.body, :length => 100), :onfocus => "$(this).closest('.preview').hide().siblings().show();" %>
    </div>
    <%= button_to_function "Show all", "" %>
  </div>
  <div class="full-body" style="display: none;">
    <!-- proper textarea tag or whatever goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, pretty cool. Thanks! I now have inplace editing for the textarea using the best_in_place gem and was wondering how I can apply the truncate function onto it...See my edited question for code.

Comment: Yeah, i think that if you just put the best_in_place helper where my comment is then that should work ok.  One issue is that the best_in_place helper might come with some styling, so the "real" text area (the best_in_place one) might look different to your dummy one.  if this is the case then look at the best_in_place version in chrome inspector or whatever, and copy the styling for your dummy ones.

Comment: Oh and the whole lot should go inside the td - don't have a dummy td and a "proper" td, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! In the end, I wanted the best_in_place helper to show only a preview of the text. Since best_in_place allows for in place editing, once the text is clicked all the text is shown in a textarea to edit anyway. To do this, I used best_in_place's :display_as option and called a method from my model to truncate the text. (:display_as => :truncate).

Comment: For the "button", I used the following : <%= link_to "Show all", '#', onclick: "$(this).closest('.preview').hide().siblings().show();", class: "nav_link"%> since button_to_function was deprecated in rails4

Comment: Hi, I have a new problem when I'm showing/hiding the text. After editing the text and clicking the show-all button, the text doesn't update and instead shows all the old text. Any clues?

Comment: Are you interested in using a JS plugin? This one seems nice: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/, though I'm not sure how/if it will work with best_in_place.

Comment: I've not had any coffee yet, but i'm finding it quite confusing to try to imagine what your code is at the moment just based on the comments.  If you edit your question and put all your latest code in it i'll have a look.